# Why not only use AbstractCollection.finishToArray() to implement AbstractCollection.toArray()

Tags: java, collections

In jdk, the implementation of `AbstractCollection.toArray()` is like this:

```
public Object[] toArray() {
    // Estimate size of array; be prepared to see more or fewer elements
    Object[] r = new Object[size()];
    Iterator<E> it = iterator();
    for (int i = 0; i < r.length; i++) {
        if (! it.hasNext()) // fewer elements than expected
            return Arrays.copyOf(r, i);
        r[i] = it.next();
    }
    return it.hasNext() ? finishToArray(r, it) : r;
}

private static <T> T[] finishToArray(T[] r, Iterator<?> it) {
    int i = r.length;
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        int cap = r.length;
        if (i == cap) {
            int newCap = cap + (cap >> 1) + 1;
            // overflow-conscious code
            if (newCap - MAX_ARRAY_SIZE > 0)
                newCap = hugeCapacity(cap + 1);
            r = Arrays.copyOf(r, newCap);
        }
        r[i++] = (T)it.next();
    }
    // trim if overallocated
    return (i == r.length) ? r : Arrays.copyOf(r, i);
}
```

Because it needs to consider the change of collection when this function is running.

But I think `finishToArray()` is enough to handle all the cases that the size of collection increases, decreases or remains when `toArray()` is running. So maybe `AbstractCollection.toArray()` can implement like this:

```
public Object[] toArray() {
    Object[] r = new Object[size()];
    Iterator<E> it = iterator();
    return finishToArray(r, it);
}

private static <T> T[] finishToArray(T[] r, Iterator<?> it) {
    int i = 0;
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        int cap = r.length;
        if (i == cap) {
            int newCap = cap + (cap >> 1) + 1;
            // overflow-conscious code
            if (newCap - MAX_ARRAY_SIZE > 0)
                newCap = hugeCapacity(cap + 1);
            r = Arrays.copyOf(r, newCap);
        }
        r[i++] = (T)it.next();
    }
    // trim if overallocated
    return (i == r.length) ? r : Arrays.copyOf(r, i);
}
```

There's no need to run a `for` loop first and then use `finishToArray()` to handle the case that the size of collection increases.

So why `AbstractCollection.toArray()` implements like that?

Comment: At first glance I agree with you, Qshbx. Your code should work, but maybe Jarrod enlights us what is wrong about it. I suspect it is for performance reasons and most of the time the initial collection size will equal the final array size at the end.

Comment: But I think the performance is almost the same @FabianBarney. For each loop, there's a `if` statement first(for the most time, it won't go within the `if` statement, it just run the judgement), then `r[i] = it.next()` and `i++`. After that, judge if the stop condition is met. So the executing code is almost the same.What's more, the `while` loop is faster than `for` loop in Java.That's why I think `finishToArray()` can replace the `for` loop.

Comment: When it comes to performance then you must messure it. There are so many optimizations that may taking place that "just thinking" is not sufficient. In this case here I would expect to see `branch prediction` taking place. But if you really want to know then you've to benchmark it.